# Modal popup opens video on desktop, but on touch screen devices, opens app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've built an anchor, which, on click, plays the video in a modal. However, on touch screen devices, when I click on the button, it opens the YouTube app (I just want it to open in a modal).

Unsure why I'm getting this behaviour as I haven't defined any media or touchscreen related styles or JS?

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.popup-youtube').magnificPopup({
    disableOn: 700,
    type: 'iframe',
    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
    removalDelay: 160,
    preloader: false,

    fixedContentPos: false
  });
});
```

```css
.mfp-fade.mfp-bg {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
}

.mfp-fade.mfp-bg.mfp-ready {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.mfp-fade.mfp-bg.mfp-removing {
  opacity: 0;
}

.mfp-fade.mfp-wrap .mfp-content {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
}

.mfp-fade.mfp-wrap.mfp-ready .mfp-content {
  opacity: 1;
}

.mfp-fade.mfp-wrap.mfp-removing .mfp-content {
  opacity: 0;
}

.ambiantHero--video {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.ambiantHero--video .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 1;
}
.ambiantHero--video .container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1220px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 40px;
}
.ambiantHero--video .container .ambiantHero__content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 820px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.ambiantHero--video .container .ambiantHero__content a.heroButton {
  border: 0 solid #ffffff;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 35px;
  color: #36383d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.css">

<div class="ambiantHero--video">
  
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  

  <div class="container">
    <div class="ambiantHero__content">
      <p>On button click, I want the modal to appear. With my current approach, on touch screen devices, button click just opens the YouTube app (not the modal popup)</p>
      
      <a class="popup-youtube heroButton" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDPE-NronKk">
        Open video modal
      </a>
      
    </div>
    
  </div>

  
</div>
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/953do8rv/)

**Edit**: Unsure why the demo is opening the modal. The modal works in the fiddle.

Comment: Because youtube links are configured to be opened in youtube app. YOu can fix that by using a Button rather than using a link

Comment: @AmarPathak - I have changed from an `<a>` to `<button>` and get pretty much the same results. It works on desktop, but button click now, on mobile, does nothing.

Comment: You have to open a modal and play video in Iframe , You don't have to href to Youtube link

Answer (score 0):

If you put in a html page a link to youtube with A HREF="htts://youtube.com/..."

On a desktop browser will navigate to the youtube page, A HREF is a failback, but the magnific-popup jquery plugin will transform the link into a modal-open solution (however doesn't work for me, probably the library is obsolete because youtube updated something).

But on a mobile or tablet will ask the user to open the link with Youtube app. This is because the links are processed by the intent system. This occurs before any js code is processed.

Behaviour is the same in your case because you use A HREF as described previously for the failback solution:

```
  <a class="popup-youtube heroButton" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDPE-NronKk">
    Open video modal
  </a>
```

**EDIT**:

Bottomline: in this case seems that using magnific-popup plugin for mobiles is a bad idea, unless that exists an updated version (if available and compatible) instead use a hidden div (style with display:none;) with an iframe to the sharing code given by youtube (the updated one), and in the link remove the class and change the href to javascript code that shows the hidden div.

Here is an example (seems that youtube is blocked due crosssite policies).

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#iframe1').show()">Open video modal 1</a>

<div id="iframe1" style="display:none;">
  <!-- here starts youtube embed code -->
  <iframe width="853" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZDPE-NronKk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <!-- here ends youtube embed code -->
</div>
```